# Ignore css file in jade

Tags: css, pug, extend

I have a layout.jade file that includes common.css.
When I extend layout.jade file into home.jade, I want it to ignore common.css.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm no expert but have you tried something like this? <script>
  if (usingJade)
    console.log('you are awesome')
  else
    console.log('use jade')
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [Jade Conditionals](http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/).

Example, on your **layout.jade**, declare a variable at the very top:

```
- var page = { name: 'default' }
```

Then wrap your css include on a conditional:

```
unless page.name=='default'
    style
        include style.css
```

On your **home.jade**

```
- var page = { name: 'home' }
```

Then declare your own style in home.jade - since this page is declared as 'home', the style wouldn't be loaded.